# Accessing firefox cookies.sqlite Error

Tags: sqlite, firefox

When I try to access cookies.sqlite found in my firefox profile folder, I get this error:

```
sqlite> .table 
Error: database is locked
```

What do you think the error is?

[Edited] 
After I close firefox and read, I get and error like this

```
Unable to open database "cookies.sqlite": file is encrypted or is not a database
```

[Solution]

I was using sqlite instead of sqlite3

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but just a guess -- did you make sure firefox was closed at the time? Might just be that firefox is locking it.

Comment: I am getting error like this  

Unable to open database "cookies.sqlite": file is encrypted or is not a database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are opening it with an old version of `sqlite`. Use `sqlite3` instead.

Comment: awesomely said. Yes, I was using sqlite. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

recent firefox upgrade (3.5 -> 3.6) brought another sqlite storing change, sqlite > 3.7.0 is now needed