# cookies.sqlite encrypted on Firefox 3.6 and above?

Tags: python, sqlite, firefox, cookies, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing firefox cookies.sqlite Error [Solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179552/accessing-firefox-cookies-sqlite-error-solved)

I just downloaded Firefox 3.6.  I have a Python script that reads my cookies.sqlite DB but it would not work after with Firefox 3.6. It kept telling me the database was encrypted.  I uninstalled Firefox then found version 3.5 and installed that.  Now I can access cookies.sqlite.  I am using sqlite3 in Python.
Does anyone know if you can access the encrypted cookies.sqlite from outside of Firefox?

Comment: Are you sure it was stored in the same place as for 3.5?

Comment: Yes 100% sure.  The path is hard coded into my Python script.  cookiePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\<MyLogin>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qc2owiuc.default\cookies.sqlite"

Answer (score 2):

The file isn't encrypted, but it is opened with an exclusive lock as of Firefox 3.6.  I suspect python is telling you the wrong reason as to why it cannot open the database file, but the version of SQLite that Firefox ships with does not have the encryption module.